# Finding a node with a specific value and return the value of a child node in XSLT

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

I am trying to achieve the following:

I need to find the DepartmentIdentifier=7IM0, but I  need to receive  the value from the child node = 7IMU

As the document have same structure should I always get the value for the child value related to the value I search for.

Hope someone can help.

```
        <sd:DepartmentReference>
          <sd:DepartmentIdentifier>7IM0</sd:DepartmentIdentifier>
          <sd:DepartmentUUIDIdentifier>95837aa7-947f-4a00-9600-0000012c0001</sd:DepartmentUUIDIdentifier>
          <sd20080201:DepartmentLevelIdentifier>Afdelings-niveau</sd20080201:DepartmentLevelIdentifier>
          <sd:DepartmentReference>
            <sd:DepartmentIdentifier>7IMU</sd:DepartmentIdentifier>
            <sd:DepartmentUUIDIdentifier>9f5a74a7-947f-4a00-b600-000001320001</sd:DepartmentUUIDIdentifier>
            <sd20080201:DepartmentLevelIdentifier>NY3-niveau</sd20080201:DepartmentLevelIdentifier>
            <sd:DepartmentReference>
              <sd:DepartmentIdentifier>7PKU</sd:DepartmentIdentifier>
              <sd:DepartmentUUIDIdentifier>c28ffaa0-947f-4a00-8000-000001320001</sd:DepartmentUUIDIdentifier>
              <sd20080201:DepartmentLevelIdentifier>NY4-niveau</sd20080201:DepartmentLevelIdentifier>
            </sd:DepartmentReference>
          </sd:DepartmentReference>
        </sd:DepartmentReference>
        <sd:DepartmentReference>
          <sd:DepartmentIdentifier>10FF</sd:DepartmentIdentifier>
          <sd:DepartmentUUIDIdentifier>320e71a7-947f-4a00-a200-000001340001</sd:DepartmentUUIDIdentifier>
          <sd20080201:DepartmentLevelIdentifier>Afdelings-niveau</sd20080201:DepartmentLevelIdentifier>
          <sd:DepartmentReference>
            <sd:DepartmentIdentifier>10FE</sd:DepartmentIdentifier>
            <sd:DepartmentUUIDIdentifier>2f176da7-947f-4a00-8600-000001340001</sd:DepartmentUUIDIdentifier>
            <sd20080201:DepartmentLevelIdentifier>NY3-niveau</sd20080201:DepartmentLevelIdentifier>
            <sd:DepartmentReference>
              <sd:DepartmentIdentifier>10ØV</sd:DepartmentIdentifier>
              <sd:DepartmentUUIDIdentifier>6252c1a6-947f-4a00-ae00-000001360001</sd:DepartmentUUIDIdentifier>
              <sd20080201:DepartmentLevelIdentifier>NY4-niveau</sd20080201:DepartmentLevelIdentifier>
            </sd:DepartmentReference>
          </sd:DepartmentReference>
        </sd:DepartmentReference>
```

Comment: Iam able to find the value with xpath, it the returning part I have trouble with

Comment: Please add the output you're looking to get.

Answer (score 0):

DepartmentIdentifier=7IM0 doesn't have any child nodes.  Do you mean the child of its parent?  If so, you could try this:

```
<xsl:variable name="value" select="sd:DepartmentReference[sd:DepartmentIdentifier='7IM0']/sd:DepartmentReference/sd:DepartmentIdentifier"/>
```